# Open Source Load Testing tool for web application with Windows support (Except Jmeter)

Tags: testing, load-testing, performance-testing

*** Please let me know if this question is in wrong forum before down voting. I will move it ***

Hi,
 I am researching open source industrial alternatives for LoadRunner/NeoLoad for web application testing that can be run on windows machines. I want to know if there are any open source tools which can provide functionality like LoadRunner does. Of course, a freeware won't have that much efficiency but I am looking primarily for following features:

```
1. Windows support.
2. Ease of Use, UI script recording is preferable.
3. Good number of protocol support.
4. Features of load generation and analysis.
5. Scheduler and reporting capability.
6. Community support.
```

The tools which I have looked into.

```
1. Jmeter (This is by far the best option, but I need to find an alternative)
2. FunkLoad (Os dependent)
3. Grinder (Only supprts testing for Java APIs)
4. Multi-Mechanize (Works only for linux)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) support is not limited to only Java API, it supports HTTP, SOAP, JDBC, POP3, SMTP, LDAP and JMS.

Another good tool is [Gatling](http://gatling.io/).

You can also look into [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/), it more Linux/Unix oriented but can also be run on Windows via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/)

All 3 above offer record-replay capabilities.

I believe that [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) will be quite helpful in your research.

Answer (score 0):

There are zero open source tools which reproduce the complete functionality of the big commercial tools, LoadRunner, SilkPerformer, Rationa|IBM Performance Tester, Neoload, SOASTA, etc..

If you put the appropriately skilled person behind any performance tool, even the most expensive ones, you will have a positive return on your investment.   Choose the wrong user and there is no tool so cheap that you will not have a negative ROI.  It is this last condition which drives many organizations to abandon their current tools and move downstream, the people that they have hired sing constant choruses of "blame the tool" when the real reason is "I don't know how to use the tool."